# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Recurring Events every 15 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Experts, 
We have a request to implement a functionality, where a user can schedule an event in SharePoint Calendar with additional (more granular) Recurrence options, i.e.: 15 minutes, 30 minutes, every hour.
Is there a way to do that?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This settings is not available in Out of the box SharePoint Calendar.

Your best option to tackle this requirement is to create a custom list to store the data and create a JavaScript HTML UI to capture the events.

Once this is done use a jQuery Calendar control to bind the data for display.

https://www.itunity.com/article/fullcalendar-plugin-sharepoint-2013-apps-2893